# how to fill in certain values where rowname and column name are identical

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ee=1:4,
  bb = 4:7,
  cc =4:7,
  dd = 2:5
)  
rownames(dat) <- colnames(dat)
dat
   ee bb cc dd
ee  1  4  4  2
bb  2  5  5  3
cc  3  6  6  4
dd  4  7  7  5
```

How can I replace the cell value to 1 where column and row names are the same? also suppose that the position may not in the diagonal the position needing replacement can occur in an arbitrary position.

Comment: Your code works fine with a data frame.

Comment: Try it. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

This surprisingly works for a data frame:

```
diag(dat) <- 1
```

But guess what, `diag(dat)` does not work.

Comment: Weird, is it because of how `<-` handles coercion?

Comment: @GiulioCentorame No... what the replacement method does here is `dat[cbind(1:4, 1:4)] <- 1`, which is fine for a matrix-alike object. But `diag` is not doing `dat[cbind(1:4, 1:4)]`. It uses some internal C code that does not support a data frame. But these behaviors are really confusing. I don't like the idea of using a data frame to store numeric only data.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the general question 'How can I replace the cell value where column and row names are the same?' for **arbitrary column positions** use match()
(I replaced by 9 to make the point)

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  ee = 1:4,
  bb = 4:7,
  cc = 4:7,
  dd = 2:5
)  
set.seed(1157)
rownames(dat) <- sample(colnames(dat))
dat
#>    ee bb cc dd
#> dd  1  4  4  2
#> ee  2  5  5  3
#> cc  3  6  6  4
#> bb  4  7  7  5


replace_index <- cbind(row = 1:nrow(dat), column= match(rownames(dat), colnames(dat)))
replace_index
#>      row column
#> [1,]   1      4
#> [2,]   2      1
#> [3,]   3      3
#> [4,]   4      2

dat[replace_index] <- 9
dat
#>    ee bb cc dd
#> dd  1  4  4  9
#> ee  9  5  5  3
#> cc  3  6  9  4
#> bb  4  9  7  5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Implemented your suggestion @user20650 - thx!

Comment: Note that this approach would also work for non-square matrices, here, if some rownames were not present in the colnames . Only if both vectors were identical (apart from the order), one could use a diag() call to achieve the task, but only after reordering, which is neglected in some answers

Answer (score 0):

Identify the common names and assign the value.
Try this:

```
imhere <- rownames(dat)[rownames(dat) %in% colnames(dat)]

for (i in imhere) dat[i,i] <- 999
```